# How to check the date and timestamp is before 20mins

Tags: java, date, java-time, date-difference

I am using **Java 8**. In one of my web service I am getting the date format like this: `2017-10-17T04:11:51+00:00`.

I would like to test if the timestamp is 20 minutes ago. For this I've written below code but it's not working:

```
Long minutesAgo = new Long(20);
String lastDate = "2017-10-17T04:11:51+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(lastDate);
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();  // Instant is always in UTC.
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );
Date dateIn_X_MinAgo = new Date (date.getTime() - minutesAgo*60*1000);
System.out.println(dateIn_X_MinAgo.getTime()); //It prints 1508212311000
```

Could somebody take a look at my code?

Comment: See the [Oracle Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) on the `java.datetime` package. Don't use the old `java.util.Date` if you have Java 8.

Comment: try to use `LocalDateTime` or `DateTime` and not Date. In Java everything with `Date` is broken because it must be backward-compatible.

Comment: Note that `Date` is **legacy now** and should not be used anymore. Instead use the new stuff from the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the new `java.time` API (`OffsetDateTime` and `Instant`), so there's no need to mix it with the old `java.util.Date` class.

You can use a `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit` to get the difference between 2 instants in minutes, and `Instant.now()` to get the current instant:

```
String lastDate = "2017-10-17T04:11:51+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(lastDate);
// get difference from now (in minutes)
long diff = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(odt.toInstant(), Instant.now());
if (diff > 20) {
    // odt is more than 20 minutes ago
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have one stupid doubt, I saw the code in Instant.now() which return UTC date. So the code what you have shared will return the proper difference right ? Because OffsetDateTime.parse is returning date in ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME format

Comment: @VelNaga `odt.toInstant()` converts to `Instant`, so in the end you're comparing 2 instants. Dates have no format, they only keep the values - after parsing, the `OffsetDateTime` just keeps the values, but it doesn't know what was the format used to create it - the format is irrelevant to get the difference between the instants

Comment: @VelNaga Yes, the code will return the proper difference, regardless of the format used to create the dates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast and best reply.